# ESB WSO2 Send a message to Postman (using Enrich Mediator?)

Tags: wso2, postman, esb, wso2-esb

I Created a MySQL Database and I want to sent some information to postman after a request.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/api/dbtask" name="api.dbtask" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <dblookup>
                <connection>
                    <pool>
                        <dsName>MySQL</dsName>
                    </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                    <sql>select * from utilizatori.users;</sql>
                    <result name="users_id" column="id" />
                    <result name="users_name" column="nume" />
                    <result name="users_age" column="varsta" />
                </statement>
                </dblookup>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="user_id"        expression="get-property('users_id')"/>
                    <property name="user_name"      expression="get-property('users_name')"/>
                    <property name="user_age"       expression="get-property('users_age')"/>
                </log>
                <enrich>
                    <source type="body"/>
                    <target type="property" property="user_id"/>
                </enrich>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

So, I logged the info with a custom Log Mediator but I want those info ("user_id = 1, user_name = Andrei, user_age = 22" from the console) to be sent in Postman after Request. Should I use Enrich Mediator? But how? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, after the dblookup the query result is your message. So if you respond after the log statement for example but skip the enrich, you should send those variables back to the client.

You could also use a PayloadFactory or XSLT transformation to transform the message if you want. But the data is already there, you actually lose it right now due to the enrich.

Comment: Thank you! I used payloadfactory and sent it to postman into a json file. Have a nice day